# How to switch to Amazon MWS from AIM?

Tags: curl, amazon-mws

I recently discovered that Amazon will be gradually shifting to their MWS system soon, and that if I want to incorporate all of our European Amazon accounts into one marketplace, I will need to be using MWS to upload our store inventory to the account.

However, our current solution is merely a cURL .sh script that runs every hour on a crontab on our Linux machine. It simply sends the inventory as a flat file to our Amazon account, similar to the following:

```
curl 
    --header 'Authorization: Basic [omitted authentication info]' 
    --verbose 
    --request POST 
    --upload-file /home/websync/amazon/rhamuk.txt 
    --cookie "x-main=YvjPkwfntqDKun0QEmVRPcTTZDMe?Tn?; 
            ubid-main=002-8989859-9917520; 
            ubid-tacbus=019-5423258-4241018;
            x-tacbus=vtm4d53DvX@Sc9LxTnAnxsFL3DorwxJa; 
            ubid-tcmacb=087-8055947-0795529; 
            ubid-ty2kacbus=161-5477122-2773524; 
            session-id=087-178254-5924832; 
            session-id-time=950660664" 
    --header "Content-Type: text/xml" 
    --header "UploadFor: Marketplace" 
    --header "FileFormat: TabDelimited"   
    https://secure.amazon.co.uk/exec/panama/seller-admin/catalog-upload/add-modify-delete
```

MWS provids C#, Java, and PHP libraries for example solutions to using MWS, but I am only most familiar with Perl. I have given a user-developed Perl library a try but am still lost.

I guess I do not understand how it can go from being so simple as using cURL to upload the file with all authentication info and parameters, to such a complex system as MWS seems to be.

Where do I start? I have tried using AMTU2 (a program that integrates with MWS for you) but sadly it does not contain a feature to purge-replace the inventory that already exists on Amazon, which we need to do on occasion if there is some wrong items listed for whatever reason (usually an in-store crash of our database).

Is there no simple script that I can run on my linux machine every hour through its crontab that will upload our inventory flat file to Amazon?

Comment: Well, for one thing the Purge and Replace flag for MWS flat-file feed uploads has a throttle that will only allow one Purge-and-Replace per 24 hr, so you won't be able to run this on a crontab every hour.

Comment: yes, sorry, by "on occasion" I meant like using the Purge-Replace once a month or so, only when our in-store database crashes or something. The hourly will just be add-delete.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your eye on this thread if you are not already.

http://www.amazonsellercommunity.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=190537&tstart=0

I'm sure they'll have something available for Perl users before going completely to MWS, as you are not alone in this boat and the last thing Amazon is going to want to do is leave good sellers out in the cold.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you found this by now, but if anyone's still looking they put a "AIM to Amazon MWS Migration Guide" here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/soap-aim-faq.html/179-4306905-9431333

As for integrating with Perl, I don't know what to tell you. The PHP library eventually still uses cURL for the requests and responses (and I suspect the other libraries do, too). The trick is getting the signature and other parameters in the request correct.

Diving into the docs, the code, and the scratchpad is the only advice I can give you. Especially the scratchpad. All the libraries they offer are object-oriented and very un-Perl-like, but it might be worth looking at them if only to look at the Samples directory.